# How can you do a clean shutdown of Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows-explorer

Windows Explorer is the default shell under Windows (since Windows 95).

Sometimes you need to restart it, so my usual way is to kill it using the Task Manager (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>, click on `Processes`, select explorer.exe, click on `End Process`).

Is there a way to *cleanly* shut down / close Windows Explorer without logging out?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I know you can do this in Windows 7, and perhaps Vista by holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> and right clicking on the background of the opened start menu. You will get two options, "Properties" and "Exit Explorer":

[image]

I don't know for certain which version of windows this was introduced in, perhaps someone else does?

In **Windows 8**, **Windows 8.1** and **Windows 10**, you have to do the Ctrl-Shift-right-click on an empty part of the task bar to get the "Exit Explorer" option.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in Windows 7 64bit SP1. Maybe it is because I've switched off stuff like Aero and use the [Classic (Win95-XP-Style) Start Menu](http://classicshell.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: @Jonas Since it's a feature of the Start Menu, I think your replacement Start Menu component would also have to implement this functionality.

Comment: I finally realized that you really mean to *open* the start menu and then do the Ctrl-Shift-Click on the opened start menu. I had always tried right-clicking on the start button, that's why it didn't work for me. I added a screenshot for further reference...

Comment: This method is available since Windows Vista: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aaron_margosis/archive/2007/07/17/how-to-cleanly-stop-explorer-exe-on-windows-vista.aspx

Answer (score 3):

While Neil's answer works using the mouse, in [this newsgroup post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/microsoft.public.windowsxp.customize/DdPQsvpKeHY/7udb9x6sNt8J) from 2005 **I found a solution which works** with the keyboard, and given the date has apparently **existed since Windows XP** at least:

1. <kbd>Win</kbd>
2. <kbd>Esc</kbd>
3. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>
4. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>

Comment: Faster way: Win+M / Alt+F4 / Ctrl+Alt+Shift+Esc

Comment: I've found an earlier reference in a MSDN blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jeffdav/archive/2004/07/22/191636.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Neil's method also works for `Windows 8` and `8.1`, here's how:

1. Hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>
2. Right mouse click on the **taskbar**
3. Select `Exit Explorer`

Comment: How does one start it back up? Do you have log out and then log back in again?

Comment: This is what I do: Ctrl+Alt+Del, Task Manager, File > Run new task > explorer

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+Esc will bring up the Task Manager directly.

Comment: Sorry - didn't see your answer before adding this content to the top answer! +1 ...